# Is there a way to implement custom UIApplication for iOS for NativeScript app?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a custom implementation of the *UIApplication* for iOS and I want to know if there is a way pass that to *UIApplicationMain*. I looked thru the implementation on github but don't see any way to take external class for *UIApplicationMain*.

Comment: It's not officially supported. May be if you disclose the purpose, you might hear some alternative ideas here.

Comment: You do mean `UIApplication` and not `UIApplicationDelegate`, right? If you just want the latter, that much is supported: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#ios-uiapplicationdelegate you can also get a reference to the `UIApplication` in there. But as for reimplementing `UIApplication` itself, I don't know.

Comment: @Manoj, I have a requirement of locking the app when it is idle for configurable time. There are easier ways to implement it using **UIApplication**

Comment: @JamieBirch, I am referring to **UIApplication** here and not the delegate. I understand how to develop custom **UIApplicationDelegate**.

Comment: @slolam it seems that you need to reimplement the functionality of application `start` method which call [`UIApplicationMain`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1622933-uiapplicationmain) and for `principalClassName` parameter instead of `null` pass the name of your class.

Comment: @ych, I was thinking the same. Thanks